# Continuing the installation process; Centos7

Tags: centos, partition

I just wonder during installation process of CentOS7, I set up partitioning manually with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> without X11.

How can I continue the installation process?
Should I just mount it and go back to the installation wizard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>?

Any ideas?

CentOS6 seems different because it recognized current partitioning tables and could mount it through the wizard after setting up partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going back to the start - whilst it may be possible to continue, you're only a step or so from the beginning anyway.